# C# I'm getting an error

Tags: c#

```
double dval = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
{
    k = 0;
    dval = 1;
    for (int j = Cols - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        colIndex = (i + j) % 3;
        val *= dval[colIndex, k];
        k++;
    }
    det -= dval;
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'double' for dval

Comment: You need to show us a bit more code, such as the declaration part, or type of *dval*

Comment: Yes.
dval sems not to be an array, but we need to see it s declaration

Comment: Give us a little more code from before and after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dval is not an array, so you cannot use it in that way.
you should have

```
double [,] dval = new double[rows, cols];
```

somewhere in your code, to define the matrix you are trying to use, and then you must have put some data in it.

Which kind of calculation are you trying to do?

Comment: How do you get syntax colouring?

Comment: There's nothing you have to do but mark your snippets as code. It's built in, I'd guess your snippet wasn't long enough to determine which one to use or something.

Comment: You can indent your code 4 spaces, or wrap it in <code></code> tags.

Comment: Thanks :)
I probably used <pre> tags instead of <code> ones :)

Answer (score 4):

You're using dVal like an array while it is declared as a single double value

In case you want an array, the syntax would be something like

```
double[,] doubleValues = new double[5,10];
doubleValues[0,0] = 100;
Console.WriteLine(doubleValues[0,0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

somewhere in your code you must have declared dval as a double. You are trying to use it as an array.

We could help more if you posted more code and maybe tried to explain what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
val *= dval[colIndex, k];
```

What are you trying to do here? You cannot access an index in a double value.

Answer (score 0):

That's becuase 'dval' is a double, not an array of doubles, but you are trying to use it as if its an array of doubles.